# Android studio chipmunk layout not refreshing

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

I am using the Android Studio Chipmunk here the the about info:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 28, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.marketplace (212.5712.51), Dart (212.5744), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), com.thoughtworks.gauge (212.4746.52), ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2022.1), io.flutter (67.1.2)
```

When I am trying to any views in layout it is not refreshing in the design part.

Workaround: Need to clean and rebuild the project to make it refresh again.

Any solution for this without cleaning and rebuilding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue. Recently Android Studio Chipmunk Patch 2 was released so I have updated to patch 2 and for me it solved my problem.

So try updating your Android Studio to Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2.